# Prevent HTML/CSS-Navbar from changing height while using border-bottom

Tags: html, css, navbar

I got a little problem when using a `border-bottom`with a hover-effect on my navbar.

Is there any way to stop that? Or, lets say, give the Navbar the height it would actually by while hovering?

I would preffer a solution for not changing the height on hovering, but I'm open for anything.

Here is a JSFiddle of my Navbar: https://jsfiddle.net/ay3u7trd/

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a default border bottom to all of them and make it the same color as the background.

```
a {
  color: #ff8800;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #333;
}

a:hover {
  color: #ff8800;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom-color: #1290FF;
}
```

## [Updated demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ay3u7trd/11/)

**UPDATE** – Don't forget to change the bottom border color on the active element

```
.active {
  border-bottom-color: #ff8800;
}
```

Or you make the default border color transparent (probably the better solution)

```
a {
  color: #ff8800;
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought it would be like that. But this causes another problem: the `border-left` will stop right above the created `border-bottom`, that's why I wanted to "stop" the hovering from changing the height at all.

Comment: Well, I'm going to try it after your edit - on your demo its working for me.

Comment: I now got the Problem that I constanly have a border below the `<a>` element. This does not happen on your demo - and I don't know why.

Comment: @d4ngrs – you mean on your active menu? See my update

Answer (score 4):

Add `border-bottom: 3px solid RGBA(0,0,0,0);` to your `a { }`.  This will add the 3px padding to all of your hyperlinks without applying a specific color (the background color native to the object will appear).

Then once the `:hover` effect takes place it just shows up right there, since the border is already present you have no weird height issues.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #121214;
  z-index: 10;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  
}

li {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #121214;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a {
  color: #ff8800;
  border-bottom: 3px solid RGBA(0,0,0,0);
}

a:hover {
  color: #ff8800;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #1290FF;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #ff8800;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #121214;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-in;
}

.active {
  background-color: #ff8800;
  color: #121214;
  text-decoration: none;
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The right answer depends on the UX you want to achieve. The easiest way would be to move the border to the `<a>` element (or to move the hover to the `<li>` element). And use a 3px border in all cases-- black for non-hovered, blue for hovered.

Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/sh5a8v6y/

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  text-transform: uppercase;

}

li {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #121214;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a {
  color: #ff8800;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #121214;
}

a:hover {
  color: #ff8800;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #1290FF;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #ff8800;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #121214;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-in;
}

.active {
  background-color: #ff8800;
  color: #121214;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a:hover {
  color: #ff8800;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #1290FF;
  padding-bottom:11px;
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yy9c2zj4/)**

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach is to change the ul properties as follows:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #121214;
  z-index: 10;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 48px;
}
```